# RelationshipManager not found after EDMX upgrade

Tags: .net, entity-framework-6

I recently upgraded Entityframework to 6.2 in my application. But after upgrading EDMX by using EF6.x with ef6.x dbcontext generator, I started getting issue related to navigation properties. When I checked, I found RelationshipManager is not generated or created in the context.tt. 
This is causing issue that navigation properties are not updated. Please help me.
I am not finding any clue. With ef6.x dbcontext generator, context classes and entities generated are like POCO classes, so nothing found in the generated code.
Thank you!

Comment: Does the upgraded EDMX contain the navigation properties when you view it in the designer?

Comment: I think you implicitly switched form ObjectContext to DbContext. Look at the base type of your context class. *If* this is the case you may consider leaving it this way. DbContext is a much better API. It's likely though that you'll need some (or a lot of) refactoring.

Comment: Just to add more info. i upgraded ef 5.0 to ef 6.2.and then upgraded my existing edmx with ef6.x dbcontext generator. so edmx version also upgraded from 2 to 3.

Comment: @JasonTyler, yes edmx contain the navigation properties,

Comment: [EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("testModel", "StudentCourse", "Course")]
public EntityCollection<OrderRowEU> OrderRowEU
 {
    get {
           return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedCollection<Course>("testModel.StudentCourse", "Course");
      }
            set
            {
                if ((value != null))
                {
                    ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedCollection<Course>("testModel.StudentCourse", "Course", value);
                }
            }
        }

Comment: This EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute is missing after the upgradation. I am not sure whether we can use this with DBContext ?

Comment: @GertArnold, Yeah, it is implicitly done. earlier it was ObjectContext and now it is DBContext. Do we have any way to use RelationshipManager with DbContext for the navigation Property.

Comment: DbContext is just a wrapper around ObjectContext, so yes, there is a way. But to be honest, it's highly uncommon to need `RelationshipManager`. Whatever you do with it should probably be brought in line with EF's preferred ways to manage relationships anyway.

Comment: Thank you @GertArnold. I realised the issue is with navigation properties after the edmx upgradation to ef6.2. ObjectContext is converted to DBContext and all the entity classes(which inherited from EntityObject) are converted to POCO classes just like code first. After migration, these POCO classes are not behaving the same as old entityClasses which was having the Relationshipmanager associated with them.